# In libdbus c++ how to make use of the received signal data outside the class member function

Tags: c++11, ubuntu-16.04, dbus

I am using libdbus c++ for dbus ipc communication. I want to make use of the received signal data outside the DBus class member function.Is it possible? If yes,can anyone tell me how to do..?

Comment: Store the data in some memory somewhere, and use that memory from somewhere else?

Comment: Thank you for sharing your idea. could you please explain further in detail?